# The ordinal 3283 could not be located in the dynamic link library libmysql.dll

Tags: c++, mysql

I installed ["mysql-installer-community-8.0.16.0.msi"](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). Everything went fine during installation. I could even able to create a new database and tables for my project. I am using it in c++. Compilation and linking all went fine. But while running my program, during load time it fails with error "The ordinal 3283 could not be located in the dynamic link library libmysql.dll"

I tried various things based on recommendations..

1. Installed almost all the versions of "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable for both x86 and x64 version.
2. Uninstalled and reinstalled the MySQL
3. Even loaded VS 2017 as previously I had loaded VS 2019.

But none of the above solved my problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: This means you have a dll conflict. Check and see if there are more than 1 `libmysql.dll` on your PC.

Comment: No there is no dll conflict. I copied the libmysql.dll to the application folder location. So, it is able to load the dll, but somehow it fails to resolve one of the dependency...

Comment: according to [link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ordinal-not-found-the-ordinal-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library), it could be the issue of C++ Redistributable..

Comment: ***it could be the issue of C++ Redistributable*** The usual reason for this is a dll conflict as I said. If you have an old dll or newer dll that lacks a function in the API  based on the version of the API that you linked your code to you can get this ordinal not found type of error. ordinals are exports of functions in the dll.

Comment: You  may be correct that the conflict is not in the `libmysql.dll` file but instead in one of the dlls in the redistributable. I think you need to install an older redistributable but also remove the newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I am able to crack it. First checked the dependency using below command.

c:/> dumpbin /dependents "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.dll"

The problem was about loading these two dlls.

```
SSLEAY32.dll
LIBEAY32.dll
```

It was happening due to the path under environment variable set for intel driver, which also has these dlls. e.g.

C:\Program Files\Intel....
...

After removing the above entries from the path, it is able to load these 2 DLLs properly from below location.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\ssleay32.dll C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\libeay32.dll

Comment: how did you figure out the paths that were required to be removed after finding dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

This error has been reported on forums.MySQL.com. No explanation of the cause is provided there but the problem was resolved after upgrading Windows 10 from v1607 to v1709. It is therefore possible that this is a Windows 10 problem. The full post is located here :-

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,666244,666244#msg-666244

Comment: I think that is a different issue.."Database initialization failed. "
For me everything works fine using "MySQL WorkBench". I see the problem only while loading the libmysql.dll at runtimme..

Comment: I thought so also but the second or third post in that report mentions the ***"The ordinal 3283 could not be located in the dynamic link library***